# javascript - Using DatePicker (Month Date only, no year), Moment.js, and JSON to populate event or quote

Tags: javascript, json, events, datepicker, momentjs

Extreme newbie here but am learning as fast as I can; hands in JavaScript, HTML, CSS. Over my head though with this specialty stuff. (please be kind ... trying to get there)

I've got a **JSON file of quotes** that are linked to everyday of the year (by month date). I want to use a Month/Day calendar picker (like attached image) for a user to select. **End result will be a quote for selected month/day.** Nothing random. **Specific quotes for specific dates.**

*Year does not matter, so prefer not to use it*.

I'm using jQuery and moment.js on what is to be a cross-platform mobile app (launching w/iOS though). Hoping phonegap will spare me more growing pains.

I've searched forums and looked through StackOverFlow and some of StackExchange to find an answer. I've tried my hand at different suggestions but no success. My code is kind of convoluted but here it is.

(This is my first post and have tried to adhere to 4 space rule. Not sure based on reviewing before post -- but it is 4 spaces in code block.)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var calendar = new Date().getDate();;
  var dd = new Date().getDate();
  var mm = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
  
  var dailyQuote = {
    "April 19": {
      "quote": "Blessed is the one who considers the poor! . . .",
      "refTag": "Psalm 41:1-2"
    },
    "April 20": {
      "quote": "We who are strong have an obligation....",
      "refTag": "Romans 15:1"
    },
    "April 21": {
      "quote": "Remember those who are in prison, ....",
      "refTag": "Hebrews 13:3"
    },
    "April 22": {
      "quote": "Pride goes before destruction....",
      "refTag": "Proverbs 16:18",
      "quote2": "Before destruction a man’s heart is haughty, but humility comes before honor.",
      "refTag2": "Proverbs 18:12"
    },
    "April 23": {
      "quote": "Let no one deceive himself....",
      "refTag": "1 Corinthians 3:18-21"
    },
    "April 24": {
      "quote": "Haughty eyes and a proud heart, the lamp of the wicked, are sin.",
      "refTag": "Proverbs 21:4"
    },
    "December 30": {
      "quote": "I have fought the good fight, I have finished the race, ...",
      "refTag": "2 Timothy 4:7-8"
    },
    "December 31": {
      "quote": "May the Lord fulfill all your petitions!",
      "refTag": "Psalm 20:5"
    }
  };

  console.log(dailyQuote);

  var bCode = moment().format("MMMM D");
  $("#selectedDate").html(moment().format("MMMM D"));
  $("#selectedVerse").html(dailyQuote[bCode].quote);
  $("#selectedVerseRefTag").html(dailyQuote[bCode].refTag);
  $("#selectedVerse2").html(dailyQuote[bCode].quote2);
  $("#SelectedVerseRefTag2").html(dailyQuote[bCode].refTag2);
  $("#selectedTime").html(moment().format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"));

  document.getElementById("script").innerHTML = dailyQuote;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>

<div class="calendarPicker">
  <h1>Pick a Date: <input type="date" id="calendar" format="MM D"></h1>

  <input type="text" id="quote" value="insert w/Quote>>>">
  <textarea id="script" value="Text area"></textarea>

  <h2 class="quote"> Selected date area: <span id="selectedDate"></span></h2>
</div>
```

[datepicker calendar scroll image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8QKL.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this~

```js
var dailyQuote = {
  "April 19": {
    "quote": "Blessed is the one who considers the poor! . . .",
    "refTag": "Psalm 41:1-2"
  },
  "April 20": {
    "quote": "We who are strong have an obligation....",
    "refTag": "Romans 15:1"
  },
  "April 21": {
    "quote": "Remember those who are in prison, ....",
    "refTag": "Hebrews 13:3"
  },
  "April 22": {
    "quote": "Pride goes before destruction....",
    "refTag": "Proverbs 16:18",
    "quote2": "Before destruction a man’s heart is haughty, but humility comes before honor.",
    "refTag2": "Proverbs 18:12"
  },
  "April 23": {
    "quote": "Let no one deceive himself....",
    "refTag": "1 Corinthians 3:18-21"
  },
  "April 24": {
    "quote": "Haughty eyes and a proud heart, the lamp of the wicked, are sin.",
    "refTag": "Proverbs 21:4"
  },
  "December 30": {
    "quote": "I have fought the good fight, I have finished the race, ...",
    "refTag": "2 Timothy 4:7-8"
  },
  "December 31": {
    "quote": "May the Lord fulfill all your petitions!",
    "refTag": "Psalm 20:5"
  }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  var calendar = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");

  var dateControl = document.querySelector('input[type="date"]');
  dateControl.addEventListener(
    'change',
    function() {
      getQuote(this.value);
    },
    false
  );

  dateControl.value = calendar;
  setQuote(calendar);

  function getQuote(date) {
    setQuote(date);
  }

  function setQuote(date) {
    var bCode = moment(date).format('MMMM D');
    $("#selectedDate").html(bCode);
    if (dailyQuote[bCode]) {
      $("#selectedVerse").html(dailyQuote[bCode].quote);
      $("#selectedVerseRefTag").val(dailyQuote[bCode].refTag);
    } else {
      $("#selectedVerse").html('');
      $("#selectedVerseRefTag").val('No quote for today.');
    }
  }

});
```

```css
.pick-date>h1,
.pick-date>input {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>

<div class="calendarPicker">

  <div class="pick-date">
    <h1>Pick a Date: </h1> <input type="date" id="calendar" name="calendar" required pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}">
  </div>

  <input type="text" id="selectedVerseRefTag" value=""><br><br>
  <textarea id="selectedVerse" value="Text area"></textarea>

  <h2 class="quote"> Selected date area: <span id="selectedDate"></span></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: I know I'm suppose to avoid saying thanks or +1 here but not sure where else to say thank you soooo much, Teocci.

Comment: It is ok I'm  glad to help you brother ~

Comment: Teocci, I figured out with your help how to make the second quote for April 22 appear but it does not disappear when selecting a different date? Also, decided that I do not like look of input tag box. Got the verses to show changing to <p> tag but the reference tags (id's selectedVerseRefTag & selectedVerseRefTag2) won't show unless I use <input>.

Comment: <p id="selectedVerse" value="Text area"></p>
    <input type="text" id="selectedVerseRefTag" value="">
    <p id="selectedVerse2" value="Text area"></p>
    <input type="text" id="selectedVerseRefTag2">
    <br>
    <h3 class="quote"> Selected date area: <span id="selectedDate"> </span></h3>

Comment: function setQuote(date) {
    var bCode = moment(date).format('MMMM D');
    $("#selectedDate").html(bCode);
    if (dailyQuote[bCode]) {
    $("#selectedVerse").html(dailyQuote[bCode].quote);
    $("#selectedVerseRefTag").val(dailyQuote[bCode].refTag);
    $("#selectedVerse2").html(dailyQuote[bCode].quote2);
    $("#selectedVerseRefTag2").val(dailyQuote[bCode].refTag2);  
    } else {
    $("#selectedVerse2").html('');
    $("#selectedVerseRefTag2").val('No quote for today.');
    }
    }
    });